# How to get specific objects value from JSONB array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a column named `people` and it's type is **JSONB**.

Here is the sample data (**1 row**):

```
{"addresses": [{"street":"cubuklu", "valid?": "true"} 
               {"street":"beykoz", "valid?":"false"}
               {"street":"kavacik", "valid?": "true"} ]}
```

I would like to get list of streets that have `valid?` **true** value **for all rows**.

Result:

```
cubuklu
kavacik
......(data from other rows)
```

I'm able to list of arrays could not filter values tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unnest the array and then filter on the result:

```
select adr.address ->> 'street'
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.people -> 'addresses') as adr(address)
where adr.address ->> 'valid?' = 'true'
```